# Cutting top border in the middle

Tags: css

I am looking to cut the top border in the middle to do something like this :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0iCH.png)

How can I do this on CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, except if you use two divs and do something like this:

```
#left_div{border-top: 4px solid blue; border-left: 4px solid blue; margin-
    right: 20px; display: inline-block; padding: 20px}
#right_div{border-top: 4px solid blue; border-right: 4px solid blue; display: 
    inline-block; padding: 20px}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put an absolutely positioned div as child of your box that is positioned relative.

```
.child {
  position: absolute
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  width: *as big as you want your space to be (probably like 5px);
  height: *same height as the border*
  z-index:2;
  color: #fff;
}

.parent {
  z-index: 1;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```